# Tabel Script not working

Tags: lua

```
p = {PlayerName= "",
   y = 0,
   new = function ()
    pl = {}
    for i,v in pairs(p)do
      pl[i] = v
     end
    return pl
    end,
    jump = function(y1) 
    p.y1 = p.y + p.y1

end,

  }

     p1 = p.new

  p1.PlayerName = "jo"
   p1.y = 2
    print(p1.PlayerName,p1.y)
```

It keep giving me an error saying that that `global p does not exist`. Can anyone help me with the problem

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look here to learn how to improve your questions (formatting, proofreading, providing code etc.): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You probably mean `p1 = p.new()` instead of `p1 = p.new`.

Comment: Thank you for you info I feel so stupid cause it was so obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> global p does not exist

The way it works in Lua, statements like `variable = expression..` won't create variable until expression is evaluated. So when expression is being compiled, and if variable is local, that variable is not visible within expression's scope. Compiler will assume you're referencing some global variable, and you end up with that error in run time.
Notable exception is `local function name()` syntactic sugar, which first creates variable, and then assigns function body, which allows to access the variable from within function body.

If you want to access a local variable from within the expression that will be assigned to that variable, you must create/declare variable first. Say, you can declare it with `local varname`, or create it with partially filled data, and then assign additional fields that will reference the variable.

Side note, avoid using global variables, unless you really need something global.  That `pl = {}` looks like creating new instance's data, while currently it will replace global variable `pl`, so all objects will operate on the same data instance.